# at-rule @-webkit-keyframes is not implemented

Tags: html, css, keyframe

When I use the W3C CSS validator, I get this error:

> at-rule @-webkit-keyframes is not implemented

My CSS looks like this:

```
.sample{

    width:20%;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
    margin:0 3.6% 3.5% 0;
    }

.samplebottom{

    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:65px;
    }
.samplebottom h3{

    float:right;
    clear:both;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    color:#000;
    font:15px "B Nazanin";
    font-weight:bold ;
    }
.sampa{ 

    float:right;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    color:#999 !important;
    font:13px arial;
    }
.tpl6 .bg{

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/bg13.png) repeat;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.tpl6 .bg img {

    width:20%;
    float:right;
    margin:68% 40% 0 0;
    }

.he-wrap{

    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    }

.he-view,.he-zoom{

    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden
    }

.he-view-show{

    visibility:visible
    }

.a0{

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.6s;
    -moz-animation-duration:.6s;
    -ms-animation-duration:.6s;
    -o-animation-duration:.6s;
    animation-duration:.6s
    }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

@keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}


.fadeIn{

    -webkit-animation-name:fadeIn;
    -moz-animation-name:fadeIn;
    -o-animation-name:fadeIn;
    animation-name:fadeIn
    }

and the error is about these codes : 

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}

@keyframes fadeIn{0%{opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}
```

How can I correct the validation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixes like this one are not within the W3C specification and they are browser specific, so you will always have something like this when running W3C validation. The same goes for any browser specific css hacks.